# How to get the actual video link of a vimeo video to put inside of a <video> tag?

Tags: html, url, video, youtube, vimeo

Here is the link in the Vimeo iframe:

```
      <iframe
        title="vimeo-player"
        src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/348628277"
        width="640"
        height="360"
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
```

The above works.

But the below does not work:

```
<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/348628277" autoPlay="true" loop />
```

It does not work because the link is to the webpage, not the video. How do I get the URL to the video then?

Comment: Vimeo don't expose that because they change how they're delivering the content based on a number of factors. you can look at the network trace to get what it used that time, but it may well be time bound, IP bound, or use DRM so a direct link isn't going to be reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of the third-party websites to get the mp4 links of different video qualities, like :

- [https://en.savefrom.net/11-how-to-download-vimeo-video](https://en.savefrom.net/11-how-to-download-vimeo-video.html)
- https://www.savethevideo.com/vimeo-downloader